# Why is $f(x)=m((A-x)\cap B)$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurble and define $f: \mathbb R \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ as $f(x)=m((A-x)\cap B)$.
Then, prove that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I know I have to consider $\{h>a \}$ for all $a \in \mathbb R.$

If $a \leqq 0,$ then $\{h>a \}=\mathbb R$ since $m((A-x)\cap B)$ is always  non negative thus $\{h>a \}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

But if $a>0,$ I don't come up with what should I do to prove $\{ h>a \}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $f(x)=\int \chi_A(y+x)\chi_B(y)dy$. Prove that the integrand here is a measuarble function of $(x,y)$.